# Back up log files in Redhat Enterprise Linux 5

Tags: linux, backup, log-files, rhel5

Hai guys/gals,

How can i backup var/log files/folders ?

- Log files/folders changes (log updates) should be automatically updated from original log file/folder to duplicate file/folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand, what you need,then simplest thing might be just to specify multiple saving locations in /etc/syslog.conf, example from syslog manpage.

`#Kernel messages are first, stored in the kernel
file, critical messages and higher ones also go
to another host and to the console`

```
kern.*                       /var/adm/kernel
kern.crit                    @finlandia
kern.crit                    /dev/console
kern.info;kern.!err          /var/adm/kernel-info
```

As you can see, every kernel message is stored in /var/adm/kernel,and every critical kernel message will be sent to logserver on machine 'finlandia' and displayed on console as well. You will have to edit logrotate in /etc/logrotate.d/syslog, so logs will be rotated properly on your backup partition.

I believe this is better solution than backup with cron,because backup-logs are created *everytime* something is logged :-)

Anyway, if you will be interested in creating a backup log-server on remote machine, I recommend [NSA RHEL Security Guide](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/guidance/security_configuration_guides/operating_systems.shtml#linux2). Page 66. It helped us quite a lot when I was setting up a Rhel server with my classmates :-)

Comment: @AsamTheCamper I hope it's good solution for my doubt. Can you pls give some exampls ?

Comment: and How can i back up /var/log/squid/... files ?

Answer (score 1):

so you want to keep only one backup and not multiple backups for different points in time? than the easiest way to go should by using `rsync` in `crontab` to get your files synced every x minutes/hours/days to another folder.